# Cookie and string comparison won't match

Tags: php, string, cookies

I've got a problem, I store string in `$_COOKIE['restaurant_name']` it stores string for example: "MMM skanu", when I try comparing them, they seem like they're different strings,

```
                if ($_COOKIE['restaurant_name']  == "MMM skanu")
            {
                // always false
            }
```

but when I for example
try to print it, with `echo $_COOKIE['restaurant_name'];` I see it's printing the same string "MMM skanu". I tried using `strval()` function, but it's still the same. How do I parse or convert this cookie to string? I can also see in my google chrome cookies, that `restaurant_name = %20MMM%20skanu%20`, does it have anything to do with it?

Comment: The string `%20MMM%20skanu%20` and `MMM skanu` are not equal if you do a string comparison. Run [urldecode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) on that string before you compare them and it might work better.

Comment: You will probably also need to run [trim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) on it as well (since it ends with a space)

Comment: I tried this, still no luck. When I `echo $_COOKIE['restaurant_name']` I get exactly the same as I need, just comparising fails

`        if (urldecode($_COOKIE['restaurant_name']) == "MMM skanu")
            {
                echo $row['name'];
                echo $_COOKIE['restaurant_name']; 
            }`

Comment: I finally got it to work, that helped, thank you!

Comment: When you echo to the browser, the browser might do the conversion for the `%20` to spaces for you. It doesn't mean that's the exact string you outputted. And you don't see trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm decoding any encoding like '%20' using the inbuilt function `urldecode`. This function decodes encoded characters and turns them into  a space charachter for example "what%20" after decoding is "what ".
Using `trim` I'm removing any extra space for example "%20what" after decoding becomes " what" and `trim` removes the space there.

```
    $restaurant_name = trim(urldecode($_COOKIE['restaurant_name']));
    if($restaurant_name == "MMM skanu"){
        // do something 
    }
```

Comment: You need to trim the value as well.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @MagnusEriksson added.

Comment: Btw, if the OP copy/pastes your code, it won't work. You have `Skanu` while the OP has `skanu` (upper vs lower `s`.) Just wanted to point that out if the OP would test it :-)